# Filter PII data in Pyramid framework

Tags: python, logging, pyramid

I'm trying to hide body request from logs in Pyramid web application. It uses default python logging package.

This is .ini file:

```
[logger_api]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = api

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
```

I'm trying to do this inside the view where I don't want to show logs:

```
class NoParsingFilter(logging.Filter):
def filter(self, record):
    record = "Obfuscated record"
    return True
    # return not record.getMessage().startswith('parsing')


log.addFilter(NoParsingFilter())
```

But this is not working.

Comment: What is under your `[loggers]` block in your `.ini`? See https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/logging.html#logging-configuration

Comment: There are multiple loggers:
`[loggers]
keys = root, api, sqlalchemy, alembic, api.util, api.util.cached_bakery, api.scripts.calculation`
thae main project is quite big.

Comment: OK, edit your question with that information to make it more complete. Also your code sample lacks indentation, so I wonder if that is another issue? Finally what do you actually observe? Again, update your question to make it complete instead of adding another comment with that information.